# Return excel file from oracle REST Data service

Tags: excel, oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I would like to know whether or not is it possible to generate Excel report at the database level and return it through Oracle REST Data Services ?

I want to move the backend report creating logic to the database. And get report via Ajax from Javascript frontend.

Comment: You could write a java stored proc and use Apache POI to generate the file.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be *Excel* or will *CSV* do the job? That would be very easy since CSV is just plain text line by line and you can open it with Excel.

If that will work for you, just concatenate the needed columns with separators (colon or semicolon or what you like) to one column and you have CSV.
But you have to make sure your separator is not in your content - you could easily replace it with a different char...

Example:

```
select replace(name, ',', ';') || ',' || replace(first_name, ',', ';') from dual;
```